# The client arguments (clientArgs) given to "karma run" have no effect when I'm using RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner, karma-requirejs

I'm trying to pass the `grep` argument so that the `karma-mocha` plugin will pass it to Mocha and run only the tests that match `grep`. The command line is like this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/karma run -- --grep='one'
```

However, Karma actually goes over all tests, in exactly the same way as if I do not use `--grep`. According to `karma run --help`, everything after `--` should be client arguments. (It is referred to as `clientArg` in the help and in discussions about how to run `karma run`.) I tried a small project without RequireJS and it worked. It seems that adding RequireJS causes a problem. Here is a small setup that reproduces the issue:

`karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      'test-main.js',
      { pattern: 'test/**/*.js', included: false }
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

`test-main.js`:

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function (file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
  }
});

require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base',
  deps: allTestFiles,
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

What you see here is functionally equivalent to the stock `test-main.js` that was initially generated by `karma init`. It was only edited to remove comments, normalize space, and add semi-colons.

The `test/test.js` file contains:

```
it("one", function () {});
it("two", function () {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

This is a problem with how `karma init` generates the `test-main.js` file that is used to configure RequireJS and kick off the test. The issue is *not* specific to Mocha but would most likely happen with other runners that accept parameters passed through `clientArgs`.

The `test-main.js` generated by `karma init` is actually broken. [You can see here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v1.1.0/context/karma.js#L40) that when Karma calls `start` by itself, *it calls it with its own configuration*:

```
this.loaded = function () {
  // has error -> cancel
  if (!hasError) {
    this.start(this.config)
  }
[...]
```

However, the `test-main.js` created by `karma init` calls `start` without any argument, and this is why your plugin is not getting the arguments that it should be getting.

#### Solution

Modify your `test-main.js` to have this `callback` in your RequireJS config:

```
callback: window.__karma__.start.bind(window.__karma__, window.__karma__.config)
```

This will cause `start` to be called in the same way as it is in the code snippet shown earlier. If for some reason you do not like `bind` or need to do more in your callback, you could do:

```
callback: function () {
  // Other stuff...
  window.__karma__.start.call(window.__karma__, window.__karma__.config);
},
```